# PHP OOP count public value from inside method / Function

Tags: php, oop

How can I change a value of an public var from inside a method? 
Actually, I have this, which doesn't work.

```
class Test{

   public $data=array();

   function setData($val){
      $this->data['foo']='1';
   }

}
```

Now, if I call setData(), it should sett the fooVar but it won't. Why is this and how can i solve this.

Comment: What do you want to do? Also you don't use `$val` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
class Test{
   public $data=array();
   public function setData($val){
      $this->data['foo']='1';
   }

}
$t = new Test();
$t->setData("12");
print_r ($t->data);
```

output:

Array ( [foo] => 1 )

Comment: I try to count up a value which is defined as public. Maybe its because my Method is set as private?

Comment: Oh just as a notice, I try to set Data inside the class, from another Method. Not from "outside". $t->setData would be used inside class test. Is this working anyway somehow?

Comment: then you can use  self::methodName()  from another method inside the same class.